# Epstein zin and resolution of uncertainty

Tags: uncertainty, recursive-macroeconomics

I'm reading Simon Gilchrist's notes [here](http://people.bu.edu/sgilchri/teaching/EC%20745%20Fall%202013/Lecture%20Slides/lecture6_recursive_preferences.pdf). I understood everything until and including page 14, where it reads

$$\frac{W_h^{1-\rho} + W_l^{1-\rho}}{2} \geq \frac{c_h^{1-\rho} + c_l^{1-\rho}}{2} $$

and that's supposed to show that the certainty equivalent of lottery A is higher than the CE of lottery B. However, the CE of the two lotteries, according to page 12, are $(\frac{1}{2} c_h^{1-\alpha} + \frac{1}{2} c_l^{1-\alpha})^{ 1/(1-\alpha)}$ and $(\frac{1}{2} W_h^{1-\alpha} + \frac{1}{2} W_l^{1-\alpha})^{ 1/(1-\alpha)}$.

I know that we are supposed to assume $\rho > \alpha$, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: /have you tried the Jensen inequality?

Comment: @GradaGukovic Can you write out the answer, so I can select it?